# nodejs fs.openSync() with the flags 'a' fails to run java program

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a problem with a Twitter Bot I made, involving a processing-java program to generate an image on the fly, running on EC2 Server: after having worked successfully for days I start getting the following error message from the terminal as no image gets generated by the program anymore.

Wondering how can I solve this problem and have my bot back on track. Any suggestion?

```js
fs.js:432
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'postcards/output.png'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:286:15)
    at processing (/home/ubuntu/bot.js:141:29)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-35:~$
```

This is the main function I call to generate my image and post the tweet:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
var fs = require('fs'); 


function tweetIt(txt) {
    //Making this program launch processing sketch and execute it // I just need to use node to invoke this file in the terminal $ node bot.js
    //var cmd = 'processing-java --sketch=`pwd`/postcards --run';
    var cmd = 'postcards/postcards'; 
    exec(cmd, processing); // command to execute the sketch and callback function to call when done

    function processing() {
        var filename = "postcards/output.png";
        var params = {
            encoding: 'base64'
        }
        var b64content = fs.readFileSync(filename, params);
        T.post('media/upload', {
            media_data: b64content
        }, uploaded); // just uplading my image to twitter before being able to tweet it
        console.log("done with the image!");

        function uploaded(err, data, response) {
            // this is where the tweet including the image happens
            var id = data.media_id_string;
            var tweet = {
                status: txt,
                media_ids: [id]
            }
            T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted); // type, params, callbackfunction
        }

        function tweeted(err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("It works!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with path ? Try to use relative path with __dirname (path of current file)

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+"/../myfolder/picture.png",...)
```

Comment: Thank You! I'll give it a try, even if I doubt It to be a problem with the path since it was working properly before.

Comment: if it's not a related path problem, it's possible that you call this function before the end of image generation. show more code if possible

Comment: Thank for your help. I Added main function code to my post. Hope it helps to find where the problem is.